# Substitution in an Integral from log to inverse

Tags: integration, substitution

Considering equations (2) (8) and (9) below. Please, I am wondering what is the insight into how the substitution was made to get (9). I have exhausted much energy trying to figure this out.

Note that the (2) in red is what I think was substituted into (8) from my own understanding. Also, how the $\log (1+v)$ was changed to $\frac{1}{v+1}$ is not clear to me. Pardon this seemingly easy but deep question.

[image]

Comment: This is _integration by parts_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C_{D2D}=\lambda_d\frac1N\int_0^\infty\log_2(1+\nu)p(\nu)d\nu\\=\lambda_d\frac1{N\ln2}\int_0^\infty \ln(1+\nu)p(\nu)d\nu$$Integrating by parts, and letting $P(\nu)=\int_\infty^\nu p(t) dt$,
$$C_{D2D}=\lambda_d\frac1{N\ln2}\left[\ln(1+\nu)P(\nu)\right]_0^\infty-\lambda_d\frac1{N\ln2}\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+\nu}P(\nu)d\nu$$The boundary term vanishes, leaving $$C_{D2D}=-\lambda_d\frac1{N\ln2}\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+\nu}(-\exp(-\zeta_{dr}(\lambda_d+\gamma_{dc}\lambda_c)))d\nu$$
which is as required (though I am not too sure why the $\ln 2$ is not included in the solution in the paper).

Comment: The missing $\ln 2$ was also bothering me.

Comment: Thanks John for this followable answer

Comment: @John, please at your convenience, may I see how intermediate steps between the third and fourth lines (The integration by parts) was done and the rationale behind the boundary term vanishing. I think I got something mixed up in my own trial. Thanks.

Comment: @Abdulhameed For the integration by parts, use $$\int f \frac{dg}{d\nu} d\nu=fg-\int\frac{df}{d\nu}gd\nu$$ with $f(\nu)=\ln (1+\nu)$ and $\frac{dg(\nu)}{d\nu}=p(\nu)$. Then $g(\nu)=P(\nu)$ due to how I defined $P(\nu)$ as the integral of $p(\nu)$. Differentiating the log gives us the $\frac1{1+\nu}$ term.

Comment: The boundary term is (corrected from before), given by $$\begin{align}\left[\ln(1+\nu)P(\nu)\right]_0^\infty&=\lim_{\nu\to\infty}(\ln(1+\nu)P(\nu))-\ln(1)P(0)\\&=-\lim_{\nu\to\infty}\left(\ln(1+\nu)\int_\nu^\infty p(x) dx\right)\\&=-\lim_{\nu\to\infty}[{-p(\nu)}(1+\nu)(\ln(1+\nu))^2]\\&=0\end{align}$$
Provided $p(\nu)$ is sufficiently rapidly decaying as $\nu\to\infty$ (which is a reasonable assumption to make, and assuming $|P(0)|<\infty$, which is true since $p(\nu)$ is a p.d.f, so the area under it between $0$ and $\infty$ is finite.

Comment: @John Doe, thank you so much for those details provided. I guess here $P(\nu)=\int_\infty^\nu p(t) dt$ you meant $P(\nu)=\int_\infty^\nu p(v) dv$. Also in your answer to the comments $P(\nu)=\int_v^\infty p(v) dv$? Thank you so much once again, you made me happy!

Comment: @Abdulhameed Erm, yes $P(\nu)=\int_\infty^\nu p(v)dv$ works as well - in the integration, $v$ or $t$ are just dummy variables, so it does not matter which one you use. I used the $\nu$ as the upper index so that we have $\frac{dP}{d\nu}=+p(\nu)$. If $\nu$ was the lower index, then this derivative would give $-p(\nu)$ which is not what we desire. In truth, we can use $$P(\nu)=\int_c^\nu p(v) dv$$ and put whatever constant we want in place of $c$. I used $\infty$ because it made the following arithmetic easier.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts works as follows:   $$\int f'g=fg-\int fg'$$.

That would explain the appearance of $$(\log(1+\nu))'=\frac1{1+\nu}$$.

Comment: No.  Notice there are two terms, one being an integral.   The $fg$ term is zero, i guess.